# IPTables rule for neither of two interfaces

Tags: iptables, network-interface

I'm using IPtables and I have a doubt for which I can't find an answer. I want to apply a rule in the PREROUTING part of the nat table. The rule is supposed to execute a chain but I want it to be executed for every interface except for two of them. I can't use wildcards because I need all of the other interfaces regardless of their name (say I can't have it).

I have applied this rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j my_chain ! -i eth0
```

That results into this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 3008 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source       destination
10   1538  my_chain   all  -- !eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0    0.0.0.0/0
```

But I need something like this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 3008 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in               out     source      destination
10   1538  my_chain   all  -- !(eth0 or tun0)   *       0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0
```

The thing is it cannot be in two different rules because one of these two interfaces will enter into the other interface's rule. I also tried something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j my_chain ! -i eth0 ! -i tun0
```

But it returns: `multiple -i flags not allowed`

Basically, I need a way to implement that `or` in the interface condition or `!eth0 and !tun0` (logical equivalent).

I'm using debian with iptables v1.4.21.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried adding them as two separate rules? Iptables is a "first-match" firewall system, so it should work as you are expecting. And I don't scan your reasoning for why that can't work.

Comment: I thought about that but I think that if I add a rule for every interface except eth0 and after that I add the same rule but without tun0 that time, tun0 will enter the one that doesn't accept eth0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem, you must remember that *iptables* rules are applied sequentially (as soon as one is found that applies, the packet is removed from the chain and the following rules in the same chain are just skipped), *and* that you may invent new chains; so let us define two new chains,

```
 iptables -N chain1
 iptables -N chain2
```

and now we send packets on *tun0* and *eth0* to *chain1*, and everything else to *chain2*:

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -j chain1
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j chain1
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j chain2
```

and now you can assign your rules separately to the two chains: for instance, to delete everything on *chain2* but not on *chain1*,

```
iptables -A chain1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A chain2 -j DROP
```

This trick allows you to build a rule equivalent to a boolean OR: if the packet is coming in thru *eth0* **OR** thru *tun0*, then do... Since boolean AND is easy to implement (for instance, if something comes in thru *eth0* **and** is destined to 8.8.8.8, then.. is equivalent to

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 8.8.8.8 ....
```

), you have both **OR** and **AND** connectives, which will allow you to build any truth table in the Boolean logic.